# MySQL database does not save the data sent through Node

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a piece of code that sends data to a table through a form. It should save the data in a database, but when I check everything is empty.

I have the following block of code:

```
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    const {name, email, password} = req.body;
    
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)

    const sql = 'INSERT into acc values(null, ?, ?, ?)';
    con.query(sql, [name, email, hashedPassword], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error:', err);
          res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error' });

        } else {
            console.log('Success');
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
      });
})
```

Even if it shows me success and redirects me to `/login`, when I check the table is empty. I checked the connectivity to the database, the structure of the table, just about everything possible, but I still don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Is it possible you've disabled auto-commit?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the same database (server and actual DB) that your code is connecting to? Compare your app's connection details with the one you're using